# How to set a Scanner's delimiter to "("?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to set the delimiter of my scanner to the open parenthesis character "(", but I am getting a PatternSyntaxException with the message "Unclosed group near index 1." Any help would be great.

Comment: This is not a duplicate: the linked question does not mention java.util.Scanner. It may not be obvious that the prolem is caused by an incorrect regular expression.